# Login With Facebook Using PHP and Store User Details in Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hii Everyone,
            I tried signin with facebook in my registration form.For that i follow the procedures from http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/ this link.While executing code I am Getting Error page like this.[image: Error Page]

If Anyone know the solution.Please Help Me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: as i can see. youre trying to redirect to your `localhost`.  I think facebook doesn't wan't it.

Comment: Then how can i check it in localhost @roullie.. Is there anyother way to run

Comment: you can't.  you have to do it on a live server.

Comment: you will have to add `http://localhost/dir_name_if_any` to the facebook app settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that can help you:

- Login to your developers account.
- Select your app from "My Apps" dropdown in the header.
- once you are on the dashboard, select "settings" from the left panel.
- now enter the `http://localhost/dir_name_if_any` in `site url` field.
- save settings

This should help...

Comment: Yeah i found the mistake..i forget to specify app domain as localhost ..Now it is working thanks all !!